# Running dusk tests on Homestead for Windows

Tags: windows, laravel-5, homestead, laravel-dusk

I'm using homestead on windows 10 and installed laravel 5.4 when I'm trying to run dusk tests I get the following error:

```
1) Tests\Feature\ViewProductListingTest::user_can_view_product_listing
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY"}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused
```

Has anybody had any luck getting around this?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this very problem today. I spent like 2 hours researching and finally resolved it by following the steps posted on this [comment](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/50#issuecomment-275155974).

I ran the original basic test and it passed. I'll try to run more complex test and hopefully the solution still works.

It seems to me that the Homestead lacks some necessary software(Chrome, xvfb etc.) to run browser tests with Laravel Dusk. That's what that comment is trying to install.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue before and was not able to completely resolve it.

The connection refused error occured for me because the execution scripts for dusk in `/vendor/laravel/dusk/bin` were not set executable inside Homestead.
So i used a `chmod 777` on those scripts.

After that it complained that if couldn't find an executable chrome binary, so i installed google-chrome in Homestead.

After I installed google chrome, the tests ran, but timed out before they could finish which i am researching now.

Comment: Any solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue (but I'm on macOS Sierra). If you can, instead of running Dusk from the Homestead VM, run it from your host machine. Just make sure the DB_HOST value in your .env file is set to the hostname you use to access the site in your browser.

So for example, if you configured the Homestead site to be accessible at mycoolsite.app, use that as your DB_HOST value.

I know this is more of a workaround for situations where your host machine might be able to run it OK, but it's working for me at the moment if you can give it a try.